# JOIN between DataFrame and SQL Server table without using a #temp table

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

Here is what I have:

- Pandas Dataframe (named **df**)

  - 2 columns: c1 and c2
- Table in SQL (named **sql_table**)

  - 3 columns: c3, c4 and c5
- Target Table in SQL (named **target_table**)

  - 5 empty columns: c1, c2, c3, c4, and c5
- c1 (from df) can be joined with c3 (from sql_table)
- c2 (from df) can be joined with c4 (from sql_table)

**All the records from df must show** (implying an outer join)

```
   INSERT INTO target_table (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)

   SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, 
          CASE WHEN t1.c5 IS NOT NULL THEN t1.c5
               WHEN t2.c5 IS NOT NULL THEN t2.c5
               ELSE NULL END AS c5
    FROM dataframe as df
    LEFT JOIN sql_table AS t1 ON df.c1 = t1.c3 
    LEFT JOIN sql_table AS t2 ON df.c2 = t2.c4;
```

I understand that this query (and syntax) is incorrect, but this is general idea. 
Currently, I have 3 tables in SQL:

- temp_target _table
- sql_table
- target_table

As of now, I am importing the df (from Python) to temp_target_table (via sqlalchemy) and manually performing a join (in SQL) and inserting those results into target_table.  I would like to avoid having to use temp_target_table.

Comment: I believe your best option is to use the temporary table in SQL. Is there a reason you want to the temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve my problem:

```
query = '''
        INSERT INTO target_table (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)

        SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, 
               CASE WHEN t1.c5 IS NOT NULL THEN t1.c5
                    WHEN t2.c5 IS NOT NULL THEN t2.c5
                    ELSE NULL END AS c5
        FROM (VALUES (?, ?)) as df (c1, c2)
        LEFT JOIN sql_table AS t1 ON df.c1 = t1.c3 
        LEFT JOIN sql_table AS t2 ON df.c2 = t2.c4;
        '''
for row in dataframe.itertuples():
    cursor.execute(query, row.c1, row.c2)

connection.commit()
```

Comment: Although, this solves the problem.  The performance/speed is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server versions 2016 and later (including Azure SQL) include an [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function that allows us to pass table-like data as JSON. Combine that with pandas' `.to_json()` method and a CTE and we can do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@192.168.0.199/test"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
)

# server-side table
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sql_table")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "CREATE TABLE sql_table (user_id varchar(50), employee_no varchar(10))"
    )
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "INSERT INTO sql_table (user_id, employee_no) VALUES ('gord', '12345')"
    )

# dataframe "table" to join
df = pd.DataFrame([("gord", "gord@example.com")], columns=["user_id", "email"])

# note: requires SQL Server 2016 or later (including Azure SQL)
sql = """\
WITH df_table AS (
    SELECT user_id, email
    FROM OPENJSON(:df_data)
    WITH (
        user_id varchar(50) '$.user_id',
        email varchar(255) '$.email'
    )
)
SELECT st.user_id, st.employee_no, dt.email
FROM sql_table st INNER JOIN df_table dt ON st.user_id = dt.user_id
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(
        text(sql), {"df_data": df.to_json(orient="records")}
    ).fetchall()
    print(results)
    # [('gord', '12345', 'gord@example.com')]
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent function in Oracle?